# Schema hasn't been registered for model "Order". Use mongoose.model(name, schema) So where the error

Tags: node.js, localhost, node-modules, mongoose-schema

This is the code which is causing error

```
const express=require('express');
const mongoose=require('mongoose');
const Order=mongoose.model('Order');
```

Answer (score 0):

At the `schemaName` you have enter the name of your schema:

`const Order=mongoose.model('Order',schemaName);`

Have a read:[MongooseSchema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#definition)